# IllegalAccessError: cross-loader access from pre-verifed class in MapActivity

Tags: android

I have a big problem.

When I lauch my MapActivity this launch the ilegal argument. I think that i check all

1) add map.jar from api 3 to eclipse
2) I obtain a api key
3) In androidmanifest I have putted the uses-library and te internet permision
4) I launch the google api emulator for api 3.
5) I dont know that i can try.

Please, any idea? this can't be too dificult, I can't belive. Sure that it is a stupid thing :S

Comment: Look at the logcat output.  There should be some additional detail there about where the problem lies.  Usually this happens because a class is defined in more than one place, and the place it was found was not where it was expected to be.  Also, please include details about what version of the Android software you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problems, I know that this is a stupid error. The problem was that I include de map.jar directly to build path in eclipse and I dont selected the target inside the properties->android. Holy shit.

Thanks for all,